# Laravel tasklist tutorial showing page not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to learn laravel so I started by following [the tasklist tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart) from the laravel website. The page shows fine but when I try to add a task it goes to a page that says: 'Not Found'.

My code:

task.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Web.php (routes):

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


// Display tasks

Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});

// Add new tasks

Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});

//Remove tasks

Route::delete('/task{id}', function ($id) {
    Task::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

And my tasks.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <!-- Bootstrap Boilerplate... -->

    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- Display Validation Errors -->
        @include('common.errors')

        <!-- New Task Form -->
        <form action="/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <!-- Task Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="task" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Add Task Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Task
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Current Tasks -->
    @if (count($tasks) > 0)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Current Tasks
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped task-table">

                    <!-- Table Headings -->
                    <thead>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </thead>

                    <!-- Table Body -->
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                        <tr>
                          <!-- Task Name -->
                          <td class="table-text">
                              <div>{{ $task->name }}</div>
                          </td>

                          <!-- Delete Button -->
                          <td>
                              <form action="/task/{{ $task->id }}" method="POST">
                                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                                  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                                  <button>Delete Task</button>
                              </form>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endsection
```

This is the page I see when clicking 'add task':

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Laravel 5.4

[image]

Comment: You need to give path to your `project_folder` too like as `http://localhost/project_folder/public/task`. Or simply create virtual host within your project `root` path, simply write out `php artisan serve` and it will provide you virtual host something like as `http://localhost:8080` and simply add `http://localhost:8080/task` to access that page

Comment: On what url do you see the add button ?

Comment: Do you have URL rewrites set up on your local server environment? You can test this by adding a new route (at `/test` for example) that just echoes a response. This will tell you if the problem is with your server configuration or with your code (The code looks OK to me).

Comment: @Robert This is the urL `http://localhost/project1/public/` @narendrasignh that makes sense but where do I set that path? I'm using wamp. @joe no I don't have any.

Comment: You have to run `php artisan serve` in the command line inside your root directory as @NarendrasinghSisodia has mentioned

Comment: @twan set your app url in the .env file `APP_URL=http://localhost/project1/public`. Then use the `route()` or `url()` helper methods in your views to generate the full urls.

Comment: @AmrAly I did that, it says: `Laravel development started: <http://12.0.0.1:8000>` But I still have the same issue.

Comment: in your browser go to `localhost:8000`

Comment: @Robert What do you mean with: "Then use the route() or url() helper methods in your views to generate the full urls."? I'm still a laravel noob :) Was expecting the tutorial on their own site to work without problems.

Comment: @AmrAly This works, but how can I access my project with a nice url?

Comment: @twan check the url section @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers. As for a nice url. For local dev you would just need the localhost:8000

Comment: You already got a nice url from laravel